# How can I retain the order of multiple regex matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want is to find multiple matches to different regular expressions in a multiline string like this:

```
word1
word2
word1
word1
word2
word1
```

And have 3 arrays, one containing all the matches in the order that they appear in the string (['word1','word2','word1'...]), and the other two containing all the separate matches (word1 and word2). The last two are easy, but I'm stuck on the first. What's the most efficient way I can achieve this? I would prefer to not test the string 3 times if possible, but it's not a big deal if that's what I have to do.

Comment: How do you execute regexp ? Some code what did you tried ...

Comment: @SergeS Just `var arr = str.match(/regex/g);` twice to get the separate matches, I don't know how to go about getting the first array. I'm not very good with regex.

Comment: What is this /regex/ ? Send some full example what did you done by now

Comment: @SergeS a placeholder for the regexp to match what I'm looking for, does it matter what I'm specifically searching for? It changes. I just want to find matches to two different regular expressions and put them in to one array in the order that they appear.

Comment: Then formulate your question correctly, you dont have arrays, you want them. Also it cannot be done just by one simple regexp.

Comment: @SergeS It is formulated correctly, I said "What I _want_ is to [match the string] and have 3 arrays [containing the matches]". I didn't say I have any arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go line by line and check if it matches either regex. Then, push it both it's respective array as well as the collective array.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pbyu6/

```
var regex = /foo\d|bar\d/g,
    str = "foo1\n\
bar1\n\
baz1\n\
foo2\n\
foo3\n\
bar2\n\
baz2\n\
foo4\n\
bar3\n\
foo5",
    a = string.split('\n'),
    foos = [],
    bars = [],
    both = [],
    s;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    s = a[i];
    if (/foo/.test(s)) {
        foos.push(s);
        both.push(s);
    }
    else if (/bar/.test(s)) {
        bars.push(s);
        both.push(s);
    }
}
```